# Eclipse Zest plugin source code from github gives manifest.mf error

Tags: java, eclipse, graphviz, zest

I am a newbie to eclipse and eclipse plugins. I want to use zest project, with making some specific extentions . So I  downloaded eclipse zest plugin source codes  from the link [below](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gef/org.eclipse.zest.git/commit/?id=5f0476e52eb94351b0994694b3e89d992751d7c9) , I am trying to build this project under eclipse 3.7 . But manifest.mf gives error in this lines

```
    org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot,
    org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.impl,
    org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.util,

    org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.parseTreeConstruction,
    org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.parser.antlr,
    org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.parser.antlr.internal,
```

When i open the packages above, there are some missing files. For example , i see that there is no source of the classes below.

```
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.AList;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.AttrList;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.AttrStmt;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.Attribute;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.AttributeType;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.EdgeRhsNode;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.EdgeStmtNode;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.GraphType;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.MainGraph;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.NodeId;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.NodeStmt;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.Stmt;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.Subgraph;
    import org.eclipse.zest.internal.dot.parser.dot.util.DotSwitch;
```

I am not able to build from source ,-I think- since there are some missing source codes in [git link](http://git.eclipse.org/c/gef/org.eclipse.zest.git/commit/?id=5f0476e52eb94351b0994694b3e89d992751d7c9).

do you have any solutions thank you .

Answer (score 0):

The dot parser is an Xtext project that needs source code generated. At this point, it needs two manual steps:

1. 1. Create a src-gen folder in the root folder of org.eclipse.zest.dot.core - this will become a source folder. Git does not upload empty folders in git.
   2. Similarly create a src-gen folder in org.eclipse.zest.dot.ui.
2. Execute the org.eclipse.zest.dot.core/src/org/eclipse/zest/internal/dot/parser/GenerateDot.mwe2 workflow file (Run as/MWE2 workflow). This will generate all necessary code. If you did not create the source folders, this step would fail with a really cryptic error message.